# How to pass a generic interface to zustand create call in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, zustand

so I have been struggling with finding an answer, as to what is the correct syntax to pass an generic interface to a when calling a function that takes in a generic type.

What I want to do is `const data = itemStore<T>(state => state.data)`

```
import { create } from "zustand";

interface Item<T> {
  count: number
  data: T
}

const itemStore = create<Item<T>>()((set) => ({
  count: 1,
  data: "generic"
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Came back from the exile, here is your answer my friend:

```
// store file
type BaseStore<T> = {
  items: T;
};

const INITIAL_ITEMS_DATA: BaseStore<{}>['items'] = {};

const useDataImplementation = create<BaseStore<{}>>((set) => ({
  items: INITIAL_ITEMS_DATA,
}));

export const useStore = useDataImplementation as {
  <T>(): BaseStore<T>;
  <T, U>(selector: (s: BaseStore<T>) => U): U;
};

// Then when you call this thing you need to only pass your interface/type:
interface Item {
  name: string;
  price: string;
  stock: boolean;
}
const store = useStore<Item>();
```

With this you'll have your `item` nicely and strongly typed, so, we're asserting the types by making them to kinda lie.